# memory sharing for unions in C

Tags: c, unions

Unfortunately, description of a particular behavior of `Unions in C` in online resources (I can list few if required) differs vastly from one source to another, and in some cases insufficient. One of the resource says,  `You can define a union with many members, but only one member can contain a value at any given time.` and thats about it. And then another resource says, `in union, the only member whose value is currently stored will have the memory.`
So, now if I run this program,

```
#include <stdio.h>

union item
{
 int a;
 float b;
 char ch;
};

int main( )
{
 union item it;
 it.a = 12;
 it.b = 20.2;
 it.ch='z';
 printf("%d\n",it.a);
 printf("%f\n",it.b);
 printf("%c\n",it.ch);
 return 0;
}
```

I get output as:

```
1101109626
20.199940
z
```

The online website states that **a** and **b** both are corrupted, although I disagree slightly here as `b` is close to 20.2. Anyhow, now if I write char in the beginning and then write a and b (still same format), I see that `b` has right value but other two are corrupted.  However, if I declare `b` as int, `a` and `b` both are correct. So I deduce that, if members of union are of the same format, then when you write any one member, the other members **WILL** contain the same value (since they are of same format) which you can read off at any time without any problem. But if they are all of different format, then the one who was written last is only the valid value. I found no online resource which states this categorically. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: If a union would have the same semantics as a `struct`, it would be pretty useless, wouldn't it?

Comment: c is also corrupted, but in case of litle-endiann floats may only the fractional part and may only the lower 8 bit of it. A IEEE-32Bit float have 24 Bit Significand Bits, so you can have a relative error of 2^24/2^8=2^-16=1.5e-5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But if they are all of different format, then the one who was written
>   last is only the valid value.

You are almost correct.

---

When you write one member of union and read another (the one that wasn't written last), the behavior is unspecified which can be trap representation.

From one footnote of the C11 n1570 draft (see footnote 95 in 6.5.2.3):

> If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the
>   same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the
>   appropriate part of the object representation of the value is
>   reinterpreted as an object representation in the new type as described
>   in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called ‘‘type punning’’). This might be
>   a trap representation.

Comment: This clears a lot. Thanks a ton. Since you answered first, and is correct, I would mark it as accepted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea of a C `union` is to share the same storage area for different types. If all members of the union were of the same type, then it would makes no sense to have a union at all, because it would be equal to a single instance of that type for all purposes.

Unions can help you achieve [type punning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning), i.e. "raw" conversion between different types, but the behavior should be considered UB and is platform and compiler dependent. Sometimes this behavior is exactly what you want: e.g. you may want to get the native representation of a 32-bit  `float` converted into a 32-bit integer, or treat a struct of two 32-bit integers as a union with a single 64-bit integer to perform 64-bit arithmetics and still have simple access to high and low words.

Generally speaking, you will want to use it to conserve space when you only need to store a value of a certain type at any given moment. And keep in mind that you can have an union of any combination of `struct`s also, not only primitive types, and its memory space will be utilized efficiently; `union` will have the size of the largest struct.

Comment: I would add that this is used in communication code a lot (e.g. you receive an array of bytes, which you reinterpret according to a message format with CRC, MSG length, Data bytes, etc.). But you have to be careful that the reinterpretation at least has the same size as what you're putting in.

Comment: Type punning via unions has defined semantics to exactly the extent that the representations of the members are defined and that those representations overlap.  When the members in question are structs with the same initial sequence of members, then access to those shared members is completely defined.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments and other answers are explaining, the purpose of a union (and a struct) is to allow for compound variable types, and in the case of a union specifically, to share memory among the members.  It makes sense that only one member at any one time owns the memory allocated for the union.  If by chance, after one member had been assigned a value, but another member appears to have kept its previously assigned value, it is purely by chance, and should be considered undefined (or *unspecified*) behavior. In simple terms, don't rely on it.

Web references are sometimes ok for providing extra insignt, but here is some of what the C standard says on the topic:

*C99 6.2.5.20*

> A union type describes an overlapping nonempty set of member objects,
>   each of which has an optionally specified name and possibly distinct
>   type.

A few lines down:
*C99 6.2.6.1.7*

> When a value is stored in a member of an object of union type, the
>   bytes of the object representation that do not correspond to that
>   member but do correspond to other members take unspecified values.

Answer (score 0):

"You can define a union with many members, but only one member can contain a value at any given time." is the corect statement.

The size of a union is the size of its largest member (plus possibly some padding). Using a member instructs the compiler to use the type of that member.

```
 struct example {
      int what_is_in_it;
      union {
           int a;
           long b;
           float f;
      } u;
 } e;

 #define ITHASANINT     1
 #define ITHASALONG     2
 #define ITHASAFLOAT    3

 switch (e.what_is_in_it) {
      case ITHASANINT: printf("%d\n", e.u.a); break;    // compiler passes an int
      case ITHASALONG: printf("%ld\n", e.u.b); break;   // compiler passes a long
      case ITHASAFLOAT:printf("%f\n", e.u.f); break;    // compiler passes a float (promoted to double)
}
```

Comment: I believe unions are permitted to have trailing padding, so that the size might be larger than that of the largest member.  The specifications for `sizeof` in C2011 6.5.3.4/4 seem to say so, anyway.  An implementation might, for instance, pad all union representations to have sizes that are multiples of, say, 8 bytes.